# web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not transact with/call contract function

Tags: go-ethereum, web3.py, error

I deployed simple helloworld code and want to call contract function. It must return "Hello World!"
My contract is

```
    pragma solidity >=0.5.16;
        contract HelloWorld {
            function helloWorld() external pure returns (string memory) 
            {
                return "Hello World!";
            }
        }
```

Python code is:

```py
    contract_id, contract_interface = compiled_sol.popitem()
    bytecode = contract_interface['bin']
    abi = contract_interface['abi']
    contract = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)

    tx = contract.constructor().buildTransaction({
        'from': myAddr,
        'nonce': w3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddr),
        'gas': 1728712,
        'gasPrice': w3.toWei('21', 'gwei')})
    signed_tx = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, privatekey) 
    tx_hash = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
    tx_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
    print("Contract Deployed At:", tx_receipt['contractAddress'])

    Networking_contract_id = tx_receipt['contractAddress']
    NCI_C = w3.toChecksumAddress(Networking_contract_id)
    contract_instance = w3.eth.contract(address=NCI_C, abi=abi)

    content = contract_instance.functions.helloWorld().call()
    print(content)
```

Output is only this:

```
`Contract Deployed At: 0xeCa138D80272541047b98BB5cb9AaD578a53a217`
```

And there is an error:

```js
    web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not transact with/call contract function, is contract deployed correctly and chain synced?
```

What should I do? I have confirmed that the smart contract has been deployed correctly, but I am unable to call the function.

My environment:

geth version = `1.12.0-stable`

web3 version = `5.31.1`

Comment: Additionally, I am using PoA on a private network

Comment: The error means that the smart contract is not deployed. Please share your steps how you verify and why you think your contract is deployed, because it likely is not.

Comment: Thanks for your replying, and I'll share the code. I see a contract address in the transaction receipt, so I think it has been deployed.

Comment: How can I get the deployed contract address?

Comment: Sorry, I think I was incorrect and it is correct.

Comment: Can you check if the 1) `tx_receipt["status"]` is 1 as it means the transaction succeeded and then 2) `w3.eth.get_code()` return any bytecode for the contract after it is supposedly deployed - this both should mean the contract is deployed and then it might be some sort of other issue with geth

Comment: I checked tx_receipt["status"] and it returns 0. So, the contract isn't deployed. What should I do to deploy the contract?

Comment: You fix your contract by making sure its constructor correctly runs, or check your contract source code for other issues why the deployment might fail

Comment: Thank you. I share my contract code.

Comment: Hmm. The contract code is so simple that nothing should go wrong. However the contract is not deployed. My suggestion would to try to deploy the contract to a public Ethereum testnet and then use a public testnet debugger like tenderly.co to check the transaction. Private geth is very hard to debug.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using py-solc-x for solidity compilation, but is that relevant?

Comment: It should not be.